# Show all scheduled cron jobs

Tags: cron

How can I list all cron jobs which are scheduled to run? I need to check if my cron jobs are working.

I guess they don't even run, because our Magento does not send out any order confirmation emails anymore.

Comment: All cron jobs are always scheduled to run.  You may list them with `crontab -l`.  If this was not what you were asking, then please clarify your question.  Also add any details that you are able to provide regarding things you've noticed in logs and what your cron job's crontab entry looks like.

Comment: You should check `/var/spool/cron/*` and `/etc/cron.*/*`. Also, `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thx it shows all scheduled cron jobs. I can accept your answer.

Comment: Is there also a way to see when a cron job was last executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment of @Marcel

You should check `/var/spool/cron/*` and `/etc/cron.*/*`. Also, `/etc/crontab`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all jobs on your system and where they are defined:

```
sudo sh -c 'more /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/* /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*' 2>/dev/null | less
```